# How to update ng-repeat after POST of new items to server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Say I have a list of items populated by data retrieved from a server via a very simple service that loads up a JSON object. Something like this:

```
MyApp.factory("ItemList", function($resource) {
    return $resource("/api/items", {}, {
        "get":{
            method: 'GET'
        },
        "add":{
            method: 'POST'
        }
    });
});
```

If I add something to this list via POST to the server, it works fine, but I'm not exactly clear on how to get the new item to appear in my view without reloading the whole page.

My controller looks like this right now:

```
MyApp.controller('ListController', function($scope, ItemList) {
    $scope.items = ItemList.query();
    $scope.addItem = function() {
        var form = {
            "item" : "Some content",
        }
        ItemList.add(form);
    };
});
```

Now here's where things get tricky. I thought about rewriting the service to push the new item to an array stored in the service, but every new item has a unique ID added to it by the server when it's posted. Long story short, I need to either refresh the whole resource, or get the new unique ID from the server (which is possible, the API supports it) and append the combined data to the list.

I don't want to use any JQuery for this. What would be the Angular way of accomplishing updating the list?

**ADDITIONAL DATA**: One thing that may help is that when an item is posted to the server, it responds with the item's content and unique ID. However, I'm not sure about the Angular way to go about snagging that and adding it to the list.

**SOLUTION AS OF 11/23/2015**
Thanks to the answers below, I put together a working CRUD-ish ("ish" because due to the way the app operates, CRUD isn't perfect for my needs) solution, which I'm explaining below.

First, here's my new resource:

```
// Added $http for ease of getting JSON results
factory("ItemList", function($resource, $http) {
    var service = {};

    // Simplified $resource object for querying. Posts handled by $http now.
    service.items = $resource("/api/items:id");

    // Make the items an array accessible from inside the service.
    service.list = service.items.query();
    service.add = function(item) {
        $http.post('/api/items', item)
        .success(function(data) {
            service.list.push(data);
        })
        .error(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
    }
    return service;
});
```

Then all I have to do is change my controller, like so:

```
MyApp.controller('ListController', function($scope, ItemList) {

    // Grab the array from the service instead of querying the resource
    $scope.items = ItemList.list;
    $scope.addItem = function() {
        var form = {
            "item" : "Some content",
        }
        ItemList.add(form);
    };
});
```

This is working very well, prevents me from needing to reload the whole page, and is very fast. I will try to improve upon this in the future - hopefully by making it more CRUD-ish, but in the meantime, this works. I hope other people find it useful.

Comment: Does your server return the new item with the generated ID as a response to the post?

Comment: Yes, it does. Can I take advantage of that somehow?

Comment: In that case you don`t need one more request if you want to append item to the list on the client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are confident that there are no changes in the data on the server-side (ref. Lazarev Alexandr's comment), I would append the new data to the existing list.

```
$http.post('/someUrl', data).then(
  function(data){ // on success
    $scope.yourlist.push(data);
  }, 
  function(data){ // on error
    console.log(data);
  });
```

The service will return a promise and then when the POST is complete it should return the new returned item and you can just add it to your current list.

I might be wrong, but I feel this has a slightly more 'Angular' approach by not reloading existing data.

Web Api:

```
public class InfoController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public IHttpActionResult AddInfo([FromBody]InfoClass info)
        {
            object o = new object();
            return Json(o);
        }
    }

    public class SomeClass
    {
        public string firstname { get; set; }
        public string lastname { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: This would be a good solution except the data posted to the server ends up with a unique ID that is generated by the server. But... I'm starting to realize that what I'm really doing here is a CRUD app relying on a RESTful API. I'm going to do a bunch of tweaking on it, get it working the CRUD way, then post that as a solution (unless someone beats me to it).

Comment: But your service can return that id (or the whole object as JSON). You could then take the return value from the webapi and push it to your array in the 'on success' function.  `public class InfoController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public IHttpActionResult AddInfo([FromBody]InfoClass info)
        {
            object o = new object();
            return Json(o);
        }
    }

    public class InfoClass
    {
        public string firstname { get; set; }
        public string lastname { get; set; }
        public string company { get; set; }
    }`

Comment: That's a really good point. I'll see what I can whip up, and if that does the trick, I'm going to mark this as the answer.

Comment: Freaking NAILED it! I combined your idea with grabbing the JSON output from the server's API... Lo and behold, new entries automagically appear now! Gonna write up the full solution in the body of the question for other people to find and examine. Still not doing it quite the CRUD way, but it freaking works and that's all that matters.

Answer (score 1):

The main reason why you should better refresh the whole resource: If you duplicate the logic of data list building on the client, you can get some troubles once the logic is changed on the server.